# What set does this large sand green roof piece belong to and what is it?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

What set does this piece go to and what is it?  Thinking a castle piece?

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 8):

This part is [Tower Roof W. Tiles](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6018577) and because its only made in 3 colors and as the other two available colors are black and lilac, this must be the sand green version. Color in the photo has a more blueish tint to it

This version is only used in two Harry Potter Hogwarts set:

[4842-1: Hogwarts Castle](https://brickset.com/sets/4842-1/Hogwarts-Castle)

[image]

[4867-1: Hogwarts](https://brickset.com/sets/4867-1/Hogwarts)

[image]